# Directive not being called for element with closing tag, but works fine on self-closing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing a directive to simplify my HTML, but it is not being applied to elements that are written as `<blah></blah>`, even though it is being called to elements written as `<blah />`:

HTML:

```
<search-filter type="text" name="query" update="doSearch()"/>
<search-filter type="bool" name="xp">XP Levels</search-filter>
<search-filter type="bool" name="lotd">LOTDs</search-filter>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module("blah", [])
.directive("searchFilter", function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        terminal: true,
        priority: 1000,
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            element = angular.element(element);
            console.log(element);
            switch (element.attr("type")) {
            case "text":
                //do stuff
                break;
            case "bool":
                //do stuff
                break;
            }
        }
    };
})
```

It works for the first element, which is self-closing, but not the other ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML 5, `<search-filter />` means `<search-filter>`. Therefore you are never closing the first element which prevents the other two to work. Use `<search-filter></search-filter>` for all and it will work fine.

[From W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#syntax-start-tag):

> If the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is
>   a foreign element, then there may be a single U+002F SOLIDUS character
>   (/). This character has no effect on void elements, but on foreign
>   elements it marks the start tag as self-closing.

Your directive is treated as *void element*. Foreign elements are just elements from the MathML namespace and the SVG namespace.